# how to set multiple fontfamily where one is URI and another is name of installed font

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to apply multiple font family, where one font is on the server and another is installed on local machine.

For instance I want to use `Times New Roman` (installed on local machine) with **my uri of custom font**

```
 textblock.FontFamily=new FontFamily(new Uri("Protocol://Path-of-Custom-Font"),"")
```

where should I place Times New Roman so that I can use multiple fontfamily???????

thankyou

Comment: What was your requirement, is it need to apply different fonts for a single Textblock?

Comment: yes what i required is, if a font family is not in custom url then locally installed font is applied

Answer (score 0):

Simple: It won't work.

MSDN documentation states that

> WPF applications do not allow a font reference to an http or ftp uniform resource identifier (URI).

Comment: this will only work if the .ttf file is on the local machine but in my case .ttf file is on the server i need to give the web uri of the file but i dont know why the application not even sending the request to the server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @AmritPalSingh: Why do you need to get the font from your server? Isn't it much easier to just pack your custom font within your application?

Comment: i have already enough fonts in application but now I want to give freedom to user so that he can use font by entering the font name.I am using google font dir=> http://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg/ofl/ where all the fonts are listed

Comment: @AmritPalSingh Then you'll need to insert a mechanism to **first** download the specific font from that server to your application folder. Then you could use the default way as I mentioned. I don't think WPF allows font usage directly from the internet as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: ya I tried but it seems impossible as I was refering **(http:/MyFontServer/Fonts/#My Custom Font)** it is mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   well thankyou for your kind responce

Comment: @AmritPalSingh At first sight it worked, but after some more "inspection" it turned out it didn't worked.